# Image not uploading to MySQL database in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

The form portion of my view file is:

```
<form action="/admin/sliders" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                          <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
                              <h4 class="slide">Slide photo name</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-8 form-group">
                              <input class="form-control inbox-del" id="slide_name" name="slider_name" placeholder="Add slide name" type="text">
                            </div>
                          </div> 
                          <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
                              <h4 class="slide">Add photo for slide</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6 form-group slide">
                                <input type="file" id="slider_link" name="slider_link" placeholder="Add a photo" >
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-2 form-group">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary inbox-del pull-right"> Add Slider </button>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </form>
```

And the controller file is as follows:

```
public function store(Request $request){

$image = $request->file('image');
$filename = time().$image;
$gallery = new Slider;
$gallery->slider_name= $request->slider_name;
$gallery->slider_link = $filename;
$gallery->save();
$request->slider_link->move(public_path('uploaded'),$gallery->slider_name);
return $request->slider_link;
```

}

And I get the error: **FatalErrorException
Call to a member function move() on null**. All the text data is inserted into the database. But the image is not placed in the `uploaded` directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `getClientOriginalName` function to get filename.

```
$image = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
```

Comment: after adding that, now it's showing "Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null " error

Comment: Your name in input is `slider_link` not `image`. Update it.